# Nested SELECT with a previous selected value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I want to make a SELECT and bring the info from a column and his values. I know that I need to access *information_schema* then I need to make another SELECT inside with the *column_name* in the specific row to acess that value.

```
SELECT column_name,
   DATA_TYPE,
   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
   (? ... SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM MYTABLE ... ?)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

How to change the COLUMN_NAME with the column in the row to get the result?

Comment: How the data will be showed when the target table has more than one record

Comment: There´s only one record for each column

Comment: Just manipulate the transposing of columns to row using your middleware language(e.g. C#, PHP, etc). Though I think your requirement can be possibly done in Postgresql, it has `array` type  and `unnest` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you want this if there are more than one row in your table. This will work for a table with one row. If there are more than one row in the table it will take one of the rows in the table.

```
SELECT I.COLUMN_NAME,
       I.DATA_TYPE,
       I.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
       (
       SELECT T.X.value('/*[local-name(.)=sql:column("I.COLUMN_NAME")][1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
       FROM 
         (
         SELECT *
         FROM MyTable
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ) AS T(X)
       ) AS COLUMN_VALUE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS I
WHERE I.TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
ORDER BY I.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2abfe/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

In any case you are interested how it is done on Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/dea17/1

```
create table beatles(firstname text,middlename text,lastname text, age int);

insert into beatles(firstname,middlename,lastname,age)
values('John','Winston','Lennon',40);



select c.column_name, x.arr[c.ordinal_position]
from information_schema.columns c
cross join 
    ( select avals (hstore(b)) as arr from (select * from beatles) as b  ) as x
where c.table_schema = 'public' and c.table_name = 'beatles'
order by c.ordinal_position
```

Output:

```
| COLUMN_NAME |     ARR |
-------------------------
|   firstname |    John |
|  middlename | Winston |
|    lastname |  Lennon |
|         age |      40 |
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/dea17/1